# Positive power of an invertible matrix with complex entries is diagonalizable only if the matrix itself is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that a positive power of an invertible matrix with complex entries is diagonalizable only if the matrix itself is diagonalizable.

The other direction is trivial. This direction seems a little more involved. I'm not sure if it's best to start by assuming $A$ is not diagonalizable and get that $A^k$ isn't as well. Or to start from diagonalization of $A^k$ and work one out for $A$.

First method: $A$ has non trivial Jordan block. Powers of this block are upper triangular Toeplitz matrices. This means we have generalized eigenvectors and thus we don't have diagonalizability.

Second method: If $A^k$ is diagonalizable, consider it's minimal polynomial, $m$, i.e. the monic polynomial of smallest degree such that $m(A^k)=0$. We have that $m$ factors linearly with no repeated roots. Invertibility gives that none of the eigenvalues can be zero. I'm not sure where to go from here...

Comment: If $A^k$ is diagonalizable then $A^k=S^{-1}\Delta S$. Now, $\Delta=\mathrm{diag}(a_1,...,a_n)$ and $a_i\in\mathbb{C}$ for all $i$. In particular, $\sqrt[k]{a_i}\in\mathbb{C}$. Define $\sqrt[k]{\Delta}=\mathrm{diag}(\sqrt[k]{a_1},...)$. Then the question is: let $B=S^{-1}\sqrt[k]{\Delta}S$, is $B=A$? Or, better, does it exist a matrix $M$ such that $B=M^{-1}AM$? Clearly $B^{k}=A^{k}$.

Comment: The first method looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your first method of proof works perfectly well.  However, just for the fun of it, let's approach this from the minimal polynomial perspective.

Suppose that $A^k$ is diagonalizable.  It follows that $A^k$ satisfies its minimal polynomial
$$
p(x) = \prod_{\ell = 1}^m (x - \lambda_\ell)
$$
with each $\lambda_\ell$ distinct.
That is, for $p$ as above, $p(A^k) = 0$.

---

First, we consider the case in which $|\lambda_\ell|$ are all distinct. Now, we note that
$$
x^k - \lambda_\ell = \prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (x - \omega^j\sqrt[k]{\lambda_\ell})
$$
where $\omega = e^{2\pi i/k}$ is the usual $k$th root of $1$.  Defining $q(x) = p(x^k)$, we note that $q(A) = 0$, so that the minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide $q$.  However, we can write
$$
q(x) = 
p(x^k) = \prod_{\ell = 1}^m (x^k - \lambda_\ell) = 
\prod_{\ell = 1}^m
\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (x - \omega^j\sqrt[k]{\lambda_\ell})
$$
That is, $q$ is the product of distinct linear factors.  Thus $A$ would be diagonalizable.

---

Next, we consider $A^k$, restricted to any span of eigenspaces so that each $|\lambda_\ell|$ is the same.  That is, without loss of generality, we have
$$
S^{-1}A^kS = k \pmatrix{\lambda_1\\&\ddots \\ && \lambda_n}
$$
for some constant $k > 0$ and $|\lambda_\ell| = 1$.  It suffices to prove that, in this case, $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: It seems like I'm missing something here...

It should be enough to show that $A$ is diagonalizable over the eigenspaces of $A^k$, though I have yet to justify this.  In that case, call the restriction of $A$ to that space $B$.  $B$ satisfies 
$$
B^k - \lambda I = 0
$$
and factoring shows that $B$ must be diagonalizable. Since $A$ is diagonalizable over each eigenspace of $A^k$, we can conclude (somehow) that $A$ is itself diagonalizable.