# If $A$ is invertible and $A^n$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, diagonalization

I'm attempting to understand a proof presented on this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix

The claim is as follows:

> Let $A$ be a matrix over $F$. If $A$ is diagonalizable, then so is any power of it. Conversely, if $A$ is invertible, $F$ is algebraically closed, and $A^n$ is diagonalizable for some $n$ that is not an integer multiple of the characteristic of $F$, then $A$ is diagonalizable.

This is the provided proof:

If $A^n$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ is annihilated by some polynomial ${\displaystyle \left(x^{n}-\lambda _{1}\right)\cdots \left(x^{n}-\lambda _{k}\right)}$, which has no multiple root (since ${\displaystyle \lambda _{j}\neq 0})$ and is divided by the minimal polynomial of $A$.

---

Here are my questions:

(a) Why is it clear that $A$ is annihilated by that polynomial? $A$ certainly is annihilated by $(x-\lambda_1)\cdots(x-\lambda_k)$ and $A^n$ is annihilated by $(x-\lambda_1^n)\cdots(x-\lambda_k^n)$ (as powers of matrices have powers of eigenvalues as their eigenvalues), but I don't see the connection to Wikipedia's claim.

(b) What tells us that there is no multiple root? It's clear to me that $\lambda_j\neq0$ ($A$ is invertible implies $A^n$ is invertible implies $A^n$ does not have $0$ as an eigenvalue), but why can't two of the $\lambda_j$'s be equal? What says that we have distinct eigenvalues?

(c) Any polynomial that annihilates a matrix certainly is a multiple of the minimal polynomial...but why does this tell us that $A$ is diagonalizable?

(d) Earlier in the article, the following is claimed: A matrix or linear map is diagonalizable over the field $F$ if and only if its minimal polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors over $F$. If questions (a) and (b) are resolved, I can see how this would imply (c), but why is this claim true?

---

Here is another approach to this problem, but this one seems to be more complicated than what is presented on Wikipedia. [Positive power of an invertible matrix with complex entries is diagonalizable only if the matrix itself is diagonalizable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186552/positive-power-of-an-invertible-matrix-with-complex-entries-is-diagonalizable-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)

quote: `An endomorphism φ of a finite dimensional vector space over a field F is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial factors completely over F into distinct linear factors. The fact that there is only one factor X − λ for every eigenvalue λ means that the generalized eigenspace for λ is the same as the eigenspace for λ: every Jordan block has size 1.`

Some quick justifications here: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/minimal.pdf

So since we supposed $A^n$ diagonalisable, it has such a minimal polynomial $\mu(x)=\prod(x-\lambda_i)$ with distinct $\lambda_i$ that satisfies $\mu(A^n)=0$

But $\mu(A^n)=0$ also means that $M(A)=0$ where $M(x)=\prod(x^n-\lambda_i)$ or equivalently $M(x)=\mu(x^n)$.

Now if the $\lambda_i=r_ie^{i\theta_i}$ are distinct then so are their k-roots.

Indeed $(\lambda_1)^{1/n}=(\lambda_2)^{1/n}\implies\begin{cases} r_1=r_2\\ \frac{\theta_1+2n_1\pi}n=\frac{\theta_2+2n_2\pi}n+2m\pi\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases} r_1=r_2\\ \theta_1=\theta_2\pmod{2\pi}\end{cases}\implies \lambda_1=\lambda_2$

(We get the result by contraposition).

Considering now the minimal polynomial of $A$, it has to divide $M(x)$, but we have just seen that because of the hypothesis made on $F$, that $M$ is completely split, and all the linear factors are distinct.

Coming back to the quote at the beginning, it means that $A$ itself should be diagonalisable.

Comment: It seems as though your proof that distinct eigenvalues have distinct roots is the converse of what we need. We know that the $\lambda_i$'s are distinct eigenvalues of $A^k$, and we need to show that $(\lambda_i)^{1/k}$ are distinct eigenvalues of $A$. Also, you changed notation from the original question ($n$ to $k$), but that's not a big deal.

Comment: Nevermind, I see you proved the contrapositive.

Comment: yep, I edited. ;

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but now I'm wondering where the assumption that $A$ is invertible comes into play

Comment: I've posted another question that is in the setting of an operator on a vector space over the complex numbers. I believe there is a much simpler solution, but I'm skeptical. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027880/invertible-linear-operator-with-diagonalizable-power-is-diagonalizable

Comment: @zwim can't we simplify the remark about $k$-th roots as: if $w = k$ are $k$-th roots of $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$, then $\lambda_i  = w^k = z^k = \lambda_j$?

Comment: The invertibility is just to avoid these $\lambda_i=0$, since then a divisor of $x^n$ is not necessarily $x$ but any power $x^k$ with $k=1..n$. @Guido, yes I detailled only because OP seemed confused about it.

Answer (score 2):

That passage was [written](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Diagonalizable_matrix&type=revision&diff=322122580&oldid=301230393) by a user with a Japanese user name "TakuyaMurata". I suppose what he meant was actually this: suppose $F$ is an algebraically closed field and $n>0$ is not an integer multiple of $\operatorname{char}(F)$. If $A$ is invertible and $A^n$ is diagonalisable over $F$, then:

1. $f(x)=(x^n-\lambda_1)\cdots(x^n-\lambda_k)$ annihilates $A$, where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $A^n$.
2. Since the $\lambda_i$s are distinct, $x^n-\lambda_i$ and $x^n-\lambda_j$ have not any common root when $i\ne j$. As $g(x):=x^n-\lambda_i$ and $g'(x)=nx^{n-1}$ also have no common roots (because $\lambda_i\ne0$ and $n\ne0$ --- we have used the assumptions that $A$ is invertible and $n$ is not an integer multiple of $\operatorname{char} F$ here), we see that $f$ has not any multiple roots.
3. As the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $A$ divides $f(x)$, $m$ also has not any multiple roots.
4. Therefore, $m$ is a product of distinct linear factors (note that $m$ splits because $F$ by assumption is algebraically closed). Hence $A$ is diagonalisable over $F$.